# SAS: Calculating rolling skew of previous 30 days

Tags: sas, proc, skew

I want to calculate the skew of a timeseries (stock returns) of the previous 30 days on a rolling basis (thus, getting daily values).

Dataset looks like:

```
Stock   date    month   year    return
1SF7    1/07/2016   7   2016    0.94
1SF7    5/07/2016   7   2016    0.91
1SF7    6/07/2016   7   2016    0.82
1SF7    7/07/2016   7   2016    0.95
```

..........

Currently, I tried proc means and just calculate month-end skewness

```
            proc means data=have; by year month;
                output out= want (drop= _freq_ _type_ ) skew(return)=Skew_monthly; 
            run;
```

Anyone has an idea for rolling skewness? I know there is a question here that asks for rolling skewness, but the answer to that only outputs one value per 30 days, but I want daily values.

Thankful for any input! 
Marc

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS? If so, look at PROC EXPAND. Please post what you've tried as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating moving average/stdev in SAS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460970/calculating-moving-average-stdev-in-sas)

Comment: If not, this is for min/max but can easily be extended for skewness. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/27e23c015eae7953eff2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I managed it with the array version:

```
data want; array p{0:29} _temporary_;
    set have; by symbol;
        if symbol then call missing(of p{*});
            p{mod(_n_,30)} = return;
                skew = skewness(of p{*});
run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that IF statement is correct. Make sure to double check your answer. If expect it to be if FIRST.Symbol ...

Comment: Reezea, you're absolutely right. It's first.symbol. Thanks!